# Grid paging bar not updating in reload

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have to refresh the grid after deleting the data in the current page. But paging bar not refreshing and the current page not changing. I used the following code,

```
           grid.getStore().reload();
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload method of store "Reloads the store using the last options passed to the load method."
You can pass object containing options which may override the options passed to the previous load call.

refer : [Ext.data.Store-method-reload](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-reload)

try : `grid.store.reload({params:{start:0,limit:10}})`

Answer (score 0):

Call the refresh button of paging tool bar programatically..

```
grid.getDockedItems('pagingtoolbar')[0].doRefresh();
```